# how to calculate area under receiver operating characteristic(AUROC) while training a neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am training a deep neural network where the model is training normally with 'accuracy' metric. Now I would like to keep track of AUROC score as well alongside accuracy. I can use scikit-learn for machine learning models such as Logistic Regression but how can I calculate AUROC score for a neural network consists of three to four layers. If somebody can help me. Thank you.

Note: I am using TensorFlow for the training

The code is:

from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
import tensorflow

def auroc(y_true, y_pred):
return tensorflow.py_function(roc_auc_score, (y_true, y_pred), tensorflow.double)

then, using this as:

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='ADAM',metrics=['accuracy',auroc])

Getting errors:
ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 62 but received input with shape (None, 12)

warnings.warn("Estimator fit failed. The score on this train-test"

Comment: I think it's easily achievable. But you should add some minimal code regarding what you want.

Comment: I have the code which I am using. The errors are as above.

Comment: Tensorflow provides library to compute AUC of ROC i.e.,  `tf.keras.metrics.AUC`. For more details about the library find [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/AUC?version=nightly). Thanks!